# How to set margins in ie7 to printing Continous Form(invoice)?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to print invoice. But top whatever i do to setting margins, it doesn't fit on paper. Do you have any idea to get print out invoice to continues form ?

PS. I am coding with ASP.NET and printing out by IE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted a div which is covering whole divs. I set it position relative and children divs of its, absoulute. So i could show the things at

margin-left : -40px

and

margin-top : 50px .